# Call Delphi DLL from C++\CLI with many parameters

Tags: delphi, c++-cli, delphi-2010

I have Delphi 2010 built DLL with two methods:

```
function Foo1(a, b: Integer):PChar; export; stdcall;
function Foo2(a, b, c:Integer):PChar; export; stdcall;

exports Foo1, Foo2;
```

Each of them returns `Result := PChar('Test')` .

My C++\CLI code

in header

```
typedef const wchar_t* (*pFUNC1)(int a, int b);
pFUNC1 TestFoo1;

typedef const wchar_t* (*pFUNC2)(int a, int b, int c);
pFUNC2 TestFoo2;
```

Initialize by `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` functions.
Usage: `TestFoo1(0,0)` and `TestFoo2(0,0,0)`;

Both works in Release mode.
But in Debug mode Foo2 is being aborted.

Please advise what is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you have calling convention mismatch. Change the `stdcall` in the Delphi to `cdecl` to match your C++/CLI code.

As an aside, you will need to be careful with the lifetime of your strings if ever you attempt to return a value from the DLL that is not a literal stored in read-only memory in the data segment. But that's not the problem here because `PChar('Test')` has the same lifetime as the DLL.

Comment: bingo! it works. I use StrAlloc, StrPCopy, StrDispose for memory usage purpose.